# Passing query conditions to db.collection.find in Node.js/Mongodb where the query string is generated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoskin

I am trying to build a NodeJS/mongodb application, where when I read a request which contains either `(XYZ > 10)` OR `(XYZ < 15)`. I would like to generate a query string on the go. And then do a search in a certain Mongodb Collection. The following will work:

```
db.event.find( { 'data.XYZ': {'$lt':15} } ) // This works.
```

But I would like to do this:

```
var qstr1="{ \'data.XYZ\': {\'$lt\':15} // I would generate this possibly

db.event.find(qstr1)
```

When I try to pass the query condition as a string to `db.collection.find()` it returns me the entire collection.

I am using `mongoskin` for the application. This however does not work even via the Mongo Shell.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're ultimately generating a query *object*, not a string, so build the query object up programmatically:

```
var query = {};
var field = 'data.XYZ';
var operator = {};
operator['$lt'] = 15;
query[field] = operator;
db.event.find(query);
```

If you really want to keep things as a string, you can parse the string into a query object using `JSON.parse`:

```
var qstr1="{ \"data.XYZ\": {\"$lt\":15} }";
var query = JSON.parse(qstr1);
```

Note that `JSON.parse` requires that keys are surrounded by double quotes (not single quotes) and isn't available in the shell.

Comment: JohnnyHK, Thanks for the response!! I shall try it out and let you know.  What does  query[field] = operator mean? Where can I find more documentation on the "query" object ? Can I build complex queries using the above mentioned mechanism. Sorry for so many questions,  I am anewbie to Javascript/Mongodb et al.

Comment: @AJ0073 `query` and `operator` are just plain JavaScript objects so they can be as complex as you like.  `query[field] = operator` means add a field to the `query` object named the value of `field` and assign it the `operator` object as a value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON string like this:

```
{ 
    "specilities.specility_name":"cosmetic",
    "specilities.countries.country_code":"91",
    "specilities.countries.states.state_name":"maharashtra",
    "specilities.countries.states.cities.city_name":"mumbai",
    "specilities.countries.states.cities.procedures.procedure_name":"ssss" 
}
```

and in find pass parameter as

```
abc.find(JSON.parse(str_temp_query), callback);
```